# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Passing extra parameter along with model to action via ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

Why in this scenario is `id` null when it reaches the Action?

**Javascript**

```
$("#ajax-submit").click(function () {
    var data = { setup: $("form").serialize(), id: "12345" };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/MyController/Process",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function () { alert("Successful"); },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Process(SetupModel setup, string id)
{
    // id is null, setup is not!
}
```

If I change the javascript to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/MyController/Process",
    data: { setup: $("form").serialize(), id: "12345" },
    success: function () { alert("Successful"); },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Then `id` binds, but `setup` doesn't!

**Goal**

I am trying to develop a step-by-step wizard whereby the entire model is rendered in a single view and divs are shown/hidden using javascript to simulate going to the next/previous pages.

However, the problem I have is, one of the steps requires a list to be built up (without submitting the entire model). To accomplish this I am attempting to submit the data as it is at that point (with the extra parameter), update the model in the controller, then re-load the view with the updated model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minor change in your code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/MyController/Process",
    data: $("form").serialize() + '&id=12345',
    success: function() {
        alert("Successful");
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

This will solve problem

Comment: Thanks this did the trick, any idea why my code wasn't working? It looked fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
$("#ajax-submit").click(function () {

    id= "12345"; //

    var data = { setup: $("form").serialize()};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/MyController/Process/"+id,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function () { alert("Successful"); },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Comment: Id was still null in the controller. See accepted answer for solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add it as part of the querystring because the default route is expecting "id" to be part of the url path:

"{controller}/{action}/{id}"

In your $.ajax call the url should be "/MyController/Process/" + id

Comment: Even if I rename 'id' to be say 'userId' it still doesn't bind.